# Trouble extracting data from a NodeJS stream in a Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, node-streams

I am working with streams for the first time and I am having some trouble extracting data from my readable stream.

I am using the [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) and [pg-copy-streams](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-copy-streams#pg-copy-streams) to extract a large amount of data as a stream from a PSQL DB with the aim of creating a CSV file with the data from the Database.

Here is my code:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const {Client} = require('pg'); //  Needs the nodePostgres Lambda Layer
const copyTo = require('pg-copy-streams').to;

exports.handler = async (event) => {
let response = {};

console.log(JSON.stringify(event));

const client = new Client();

const deviceId = event.deviceId;
const fromDate = event.fromDate;
const toDate = event.toDate;

if (!deviceId) { // if we do not have a device id, just bail.
    return response = {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: "No device Id",
    };
}

const tempTableQuery = getQuery(deviceId, fromDate, toDate);
console.log("Search query: " + tempTableQuery);
try {

    await client.connect();

    await client.query(tempTableQuery);

    const q = `COPY temp_csv_table to STDOUT with csv DELIMITER ';'`;
    const dataStream = client.query(copyTo(q));

    // dataStream.pipe(console.log(process.stdout));
    dataStream.on('readable', function() {
        // There is some data to read now.
        let data;

        while (data = this.read()) {
            console.log(data); //<- this dosent print anything :(
        }
    });

    dataStream.on('error', async function (err) {
        // Here we can control stream errors
        await client.end();
    });
    dataStream.on('end', async function () {
        await client.end();
    });


} catch (e) {
    response = {
        statusCode: 500,
        result: "Error: " + e
    };
} finally {
    client.end();
}
};

function getQuery(deviceId, fromDate, toDate) {
return `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_csv_table AS
            SELECT * 
            FROM sensor_data_v2 
            WHERE device_id = '${deviceId}' and 
                  time_stamp between '${fromDate}' and '${toDate}' 
            LIMIT 10;`;
}
```

Question:

1. How do I extract the rows from the data stream?
2. Is there a better way to do this ?

Notes:

1. Running this on an AWS Lambda NodeJS 10.x runtime.
2. I know there is data in the table for the filters I have specified.
3. I have set the LIMIT 10 just for this test, those conditions will return 2600 rows of data.
4. I will be using the [csv-write-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-write-stream) package to make a CSV file with the data from the DB. Not really attached to this package, happy to use another CSV writer if it would be easier to wok with.

Comment: Is your code running ? You are using await client.connect() outside an async function which is not allowed. I am confused, maybe i am missing something.

Comment: here we should pass "data" in function.

dataStream.on('readable', function(***data***){
console.log(data)
})

Comment: @khan Yup, runs just fine. Line 4 "exports.handler = async (event)"

Comment: @AlexanderG.M. I tried with your snippet, still nothing on the console.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to replicate this, and I think your issue is actually on the try-catch-finally block.

So, when your code reached the part `const dataStream = client.query(copyTo(q))`, it starts streaming process which is not related with the promise, so the execution goes directly to `finally` block. However, within this `finally` block you terminate the client, so the data-streaming (which still run) will get error `Error: Connection terminated` since the streaming will need some time.

To fix this, you can simply remove the `client.end()` from finally block and put that client termination in both catch block and in stream `end` event handler, and then it should work.

You can also do `console.log(data.toString())` during `readable` event because otherwise the data printed out will be binary.